# How to fix OpenCV's importing errors in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, opencv

I imported OpenCV 3.3.0 SDK module to Android Studio and I saw 2 errors and 1 warning (Min SDK Version Error, Target SDK Version Warning, Input length = 1 Error).

Note: Sync is successful without importing anything.

And I changed OpenCVLibrary's compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to versions that I'm using in my app. But now it's still giving same errors, warning and failing at Run build and Run tasks.

ERROR: The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig in the build.gradle file.

WARNING: The targetSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig in the build.gradle file.

ERROR: Input length = 1

Edit:
Ok but I must say that when I started this project without library I saw errors about testImplementations in build.gradle then I changed all of "I"s to "İ" and

I don't know why (I saw this fixing process in YouTube and YouTuber said that "This error is here because we are living in Turkey so our characters different (We have "İ" character.).) but all of errors fixed.

Today I fixed errors with changing "İ"s to "I" but now I have just an error about testImplementations in build.gradle. Actually I think this is the same as my first error.

Note: I tried adding org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' to first line of build.gradle but it didn't work (gave this ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'org' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.).

Today I have this: ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'testImplementation()'.

Second Edit: I changed my pc's language to English and I fixed only character problem.

Comment: Please show us your `manifest.xml` and `build.gradle`

Comment: Please read my new answer.